# ASP.NET MVC Basic Authentication with Android 4.0 Chrome

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-mvc, basic-authentication

I have setup a basic authentication `ActionFilterAttribute` in my MVC web site to lock it down while in development, which works 100% across all the browsers that I am testing for (IE9+, Chrome, FF, iOS Safari) but when I load up Chrome in Android 4.0, it simply displays a 401 access denied and NEVER asks me for the basic authentication credentials?

This is my code for the `OnAuthorization` method:

```
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var controllerName = (filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] as string).ToLower();
        if (_controllersToIgnore.Contains(controllerName))
        {
            return;
        }

        bool credentialsMatch = false;
        var req = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(req.Headers["Authorization"]))
        {
            var cred = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(req.Headers["Authorization"].Substring(6))).Split(':');
            var user = new { Name = cred[0], Pass = cred[1] };
            if (user.Name == Username && user.Pass == Password)
            {
                credentialsMatch = true;
            }
        }
        if (!credentialsMatch)
        {
            var res = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
            res.StatusCode = 401;
            res.AddHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"\"");
            res.End();
            filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem went away on its own strangely enough, I did nothing (apparent) and it just stopped occurring.